# how to Filter records from datatable when value doesn't match to datatable column?

Tags: jquery, datatables

Here I want to show only those records who deos not match with the value which I am passing to filter data.
Here I am filtering Datatable on the value selected from dropdown list.my script code is as below.

```
 $('#FilterByClass').on('change', function () {
        var dtable = $('#example').DataTable({})
        var selectedValue = $(this).find(':selected').val();
        dtable.rows().nodes().each(function (a, b) {
            var colValue = $(a).children().eq(3).text();
            if (colValue == selectedValue) {
                dtable.rows(a).remove();
            }
        });

        dtable.draw();
    });
```

It should work like,
if 3rd column of row(s) doesn't contain textual value which am passing through dropdown then only those records should get filtered.above code gives me the result but i dont want to remove rows from tabale.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex search to do that.

Try:

```
var dtable = $('#example').DataTable({});
$('#FilterByClass').on('change', function () {
        var selectedValue = $(this).find(':selected').val();
        dtable.columns(2).search('^(?!'+selectedValue+'$)', true); // true for regex search
        dtable.draw();
    });
```